# How to run a thread only if it is not already running Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have this method that runs when the viewcontroller in question is loaded. However if the thread that its running on is initiated more than about 3 times the app crashes. I need to make sure that only one instance of the method is running in a thread at any one time, how do I do this, as far as I know this way of running the thread has no thread object name to check against.

```
- (void)observeNowPlaying{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(changeSongValues) withObject:nil]; //run the song checker in the background
}

-(void)changeSongValues{

    while(threadX != 1){
        MPMediaItem *tempItem = musicController1.nowPlayingItem; //set up now playing
        checkingSong = tempItem.title;
        NSString *artist = tempItem.artist;

        checkingSong = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",(artist.length>0 ? artist : @"Unknown"),(checkingSong.length>0 ? checkingSong : @"Unknown")];
        _SongPlaying.text = checkingSong; //this changes the currently playing song and stuff

        usleep(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never sleep. Never sleep. Never sleep.

Comment: Never call performSelectorInBackground. Use GCD. Use serial queue. Done.

Comment: ok, real helpful, could you link me to how to do that?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html#_grand_central_dispatch

Comment: I see a number of problems. As mentioned, GCD is a much better threading solution. But the code you posted makes it look like you're trying to updating the UI based on `nowPlayingItem`. If that's the case, this is completely the wrong direction. First, you can never **ever** update the UI on a background thread; this is probably why it's crashing. And don't *poll*. Create a KVO observer for `nowPlayingItem` and execute the UI update code whenever, only when, it actually changes.

Comment: Yes. I ended up using notifications instead

Comment: Actually, thanks for the details in that cause you just solved another issue I had about the background thread updating ui details. たしこまりました。